# How to fix 'The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' error in BizTalk Test map?

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'm working on a BizTalk orchestrations with a map which contains an XSLT script. When I launch the orchestration I got this error

> Error encountered while executing the transform. Error: Unable to create the transform.

So I go back to the map

> XSL transform error: 
>   Unable to write output instance. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

I already tried to do a ParseExact but got the same error

Here is my code to convert DateTime:

```c
public string FormatDate(string inputDate)
    {
      System.DateTime date = System.DateTime.Parse(inputDate);
      return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

...and the code I tried with ParseExact:

```c
public string FormatDate(string inputDate)
    {
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
      System.DateTime date = System.DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "yyyyMMdd", culture);
      return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

The expected result is to have the date with  "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

Comment: This is a fairly common conversion, such as an X12 source.  Can you post an exact sample of the received value?

Comment: Here is the received date value format: 2019-05-01T00:00:00.0000000+02:00

Comment: Then something else is going on.  That string is parseable by default.  Custom xslt or the Mapper?

Comment: I don't use Custom xslt in the mapper. Do you want a screenshot of the mapping?

Comment: You say your received date format is 2019-05-01T00:00:00.0000000+02:00, but your ParseExact has "yyyyMMdd", the two don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from several scripting functoid with the same method name inside. Just gave each methods a different name and the errors has gone. 
Thank you to all users for your time.